# Galleria in jQuery UI Tabs?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, galleria

everything is working okay, but i get this error in the galleria :

```
 Fatal error: Could not extract a stage height from the CSS. Traced height: 0px.
```

I already set the correct width and height but i still have this message.

How i can resolve that ? Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried googling for it? I did and found several posts with the same problem. Some with a solution below it.

Comment: Post the html and javascript code you are using

Comment: Is this the sale problem? https://getsatisfaction.com/galleria/topics/_could_not_extract_a_stage_height_when_gallery_on_non_active_tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Galleria.configure({ wait: true });
```